# Using React Native, I get an error when I try to use a background image

Tags: ios, react-native

I believe it may be something to do with where I have stored my images. They can be found in the `../ProjectName/img/fileName.png` 
Is there anything I need to do to load the files so they can be reached?

```
 <View style={styles.container}>
                <HomeHeaderTitle isHomePage={true}/>
                <View style={styles.quoteContainer}>
                  <Image source={require('../../img/backgroundQuote3.png')} />
                </View>
            </View>
```

When I add the above to my code, it gives me this error:

[image]

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.39.0
```

Comment: Did you try restarting the packager?

Comment: @NaderDabit yes, I have :/

Comment: Can you show directory structure? You're getting this error because you are most likely pointing to a file that does not exist.

Comment: You're going one folder too far, try changing it to `<Image source={require('../img/backgroundQuote3.png')} />`

Comment: When adding an image, you should also do `react-native run-ios` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw your problem. Should you read your source image in one level?

For example:

```
<Image source={require('../img/backgroundQuote3.png')} />
```

Additionally, when you want use background image , should you use  element is parent view ?.

For example:

```
 <Image source={require('../img/backgroundQuote3.png')}> 
    <View>
    </View>
</Image>
```

Cheer!,

PS: dont forget to vote!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

assuming you have some js file in a project:

`project/src/components/someComponent.js`

and some static file with path

`project/src/static/someStatic.png`

Import and use it like this:

```
import someStatic from 'project/src/static/someStatic.png'
...
<Image source={someStatic} />
```

This eliminates the `../..` ambiguity of relative addressing.

just makes sure that the project name is the same as the registered name

`AppRegistry.registerComponent('project', () => App);`

Comment: Works equally as well, however, I think @Johnny's solution is a little more standard practice.

Comment: In the case where react-native controls the javascript environment completely, I think using an import is more than acceptable. 

If it's the addressing, there's a known method where you add a package.json file to your components / static folders to be able to reference them by name.

The reason you don't want relative addressing is that layout components get shuffled around a lot. They get re-organized into subfolders, or moved into different categories. Components and static files normally stay where they are.

Answer (score 0):

it is very easy to do create custom control and use it.
in custom control use

```
import React from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'

const ParentView = (props) => {
  return (
    <Image source={require('../img/background_image.png')}>
      {props.children}
    </Image>
  );
};
export {ParentView}
```